# Having to scope,reuse_variables() to get network to train as regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression, conv-neural-network

In my train() method the variable where I store the logit return value from the method is not working the first time. Specific section is shown here:

```
with tf.variable_scope("logits_out") as scope:
    logits_out = network(image_batch)
    scope.reuse_variables()
    v_logits_out = network(v_image_batch)
    scope.reuse_variables()
    reused_logits_out = network(image_batch)
```

The first and second calls to network are for the original input images, and the validation images. (I test validate every 100 training steps). However, the output of logits_out would be a constant for the first call (As displayed on tensorboard). The second call, however, would yield different values (as shown in tensorboard), so I tried adding a third call with the original images, shown above as reused_logits_out. And it results in non constant guesses, however the loss function never changes. The loss function is using the 3rd call to the network(), and yet it shows no change, and the tensorboard logs agree. However, the outputs I get with the infer_out using that loss function changes! If I use the 1st call to network in the loss function, the guess is a constant and will not change.

```
def network(image_batch):
# 3x3 patch, 3 input channel (the image), 32 output channels
######################################
# First layer Convolution 
######################################
    W_conv1 = weight_variable([3, 3, 3, 32])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

# Reshape our image to matrix multiply and number of colors channel 
    x_image = tf.reshape(image_batch, [-1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3]) #64
    tf.summary.image('input', x_image, 10)

    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
    #h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
######################################
# Second layer Convolution M6-1 network [POOLED]
######################################
# 3x3 patch, 32 input channel (the previous output channels), 32 output channels

    W_conv2 = weight_variable([3, 3, 32, 64])
    b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_conv1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
    h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2) # 32
######################################
# Third layer Convolution M6-1 network
######################################
# 3x3 patch, 32 input channel (the previous output channels), 64 output channels
    W_conv3 = weight_variable([3, 3, 64, 128])
    b_conv3 = bias_variable([128])

    h_conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool2, W_conv3) + b_conv3)
    #h_pool3 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv3) 
######################################
# Forth layer Convolution M6-1 network
######################################
# 3x3 patch, 64 input channel (the previous output channels), 64 output channels
    W_conv4 = weight_variable([4, 4, 128, 256])
    b_conv4 = bias_variable([256])

    h_conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_conv3, W_conv4) + b_conv4)
    h_pool4 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv4) # 16

    W_conv5 = weight_variable([5, 5, 256, 256])
    b_conv5 = bias_variable([256])

    h_conv5 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool4, W_conv5) + b_conv5)
    h_pool5 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv5) # 8
 #was 7*7*256 which makes sense 
######################################
# Fifth layer fully connected M6-1 network
######################################
 # Our image is now 16 x 16 after 2 max pools...and we have 256 channels so
# we want a matrix 16 * 16 * 64 and then 256 neurons
    W_fc1 = weight_variable([8 * 8 * 256, 2048])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([2048])

    h_pool5_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool5, [-1, 8 * 8 * 256])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool5_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

    #tf.summary.histogram('h_fc1', h_fc1)
    h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, 1.0)
######################################
# 6th FC layer fully connected M6-1 network
######################################
# Our image is now 16 x 16 after 2 max pools...and we have 256 channels so
# we want a matrix 16 * 16 * 64 and then 256 neurons
    W_fc2 = weight_variable([2048, 256])
    b_fc2 = bias_variable([256])
    #variable_summaries(W_fc2, name="2nd_FC_Weights")
    #variable_summaries(b_fc2, name="2nd_FC_Bias")

    h_fc2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)
    #tf.summary.histogram('h_fc2', h_fc2)
    h_fc2_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc2, 1.0)
######################################
# 7th FC layer fully connected M6-1 network
######################################
    W_fc3 = weight_variable([256, 256])
    b_fc3 = bias_variable([256])
    #variable_summaries(W_fc3, name="3rd_FC_Weights")
    #variable_summaries(b_fc3, name="3rd_FC_Bias")

    h_fc3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_fc2_drop, W_fc3) + b_fc3)
    #tf.summary.histogram('h_fc3', h_fc3)
######################################
# Final FC layer fully connected M6-1 network
######################################
    W_fc4 = weight_variable([256, 1])
    b_fc4 = bias_variable([1])
    #variable_summaries(W_fc4, name="4th_FC_Weights")
    #variable_summaries(b_fc4, name="4th_FC_Bias")

    #y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc3, W_fc4) + b_fc4)
    y_conv = tf.multiply(tf.atan(tf.matmul(h_fc3, W_fc4) + b_fc4), 2)
    variable_summaries(y_conv, name="net_out")

    return y_conv

def train():
    image_batch_out, label_batch_out, filename_batch = input(if_eval = False)
    v_image_batch_out, v_label_batch_out, v_filename_batch = v_input()

    image_batch_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[BATCH_SIZE, None, None, 3])
    v_image_batch_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[v_BATCH_SIZE, None, None, 3])
    image_batch = tf.reshape(image_batch_out, (BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3))
    v_image_batch = tf.reshape(v_image_batch_out, (v_BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3))

    label_batch_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[BATCH_SIZE, NUM_CLASSES])
    label_tensor_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[v_BATCH_SIZE])
    label_offset = -tf.ones([BATCH_SIZE], dtype=tf.int64, name="label_batch_offset")
    v_label_offset = -tf.ones([v_BATCH_SIZE], dtype=tf.int64, name="label_batch_offset")
    label_batch_one_hot = tf.one_hot(tf.add(label_batch_out, label_offset), depth=NUM_CLASSES, on_value=1.0, off_value=0.0)
    label_batch = tf.add(label_batch_out, label_offset)
    v_label_batch = tf.add(v_label_batch_out, v_label_offset)
    with tf.variable_scope("logits_out") as scope:

        logits_out = network(image_batch)
        scope.reuse_variables()
        v_logits_out = network(v_image_batch)
        scope.reuse_variables()
        reused_logits_out = network(image_batch)

    logits_batch = tf.to_int64(tf.arg_max(v_logits_out, dimension = 1))
    #loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=label_batch_one_hot, logits=logits_out))
    #prediction_op = tf.nn.softmax(logits_out)

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(logits_batch, label_tensor_placeholder)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    #transposed_logits = tf.transpose(logits_out)
    #loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=label_batch_placeholder, predictions=prediction_op)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(reused_logits_out-label_batch_placeholder))
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

    #variable_summaries(prediction_op, name="Predictions")
    #surity_summary(prediction_op, name="Certainty")

    tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)
    merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

with tf.Session() as sess:

        summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())

        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        if(tf.train.checkpoint_exists(chk_path)):
            saver.restore(sess, chk_path)
        else:
            saver.save(sess, chk_path)
        epoch_file = open(epoch_path, 'r')
        epoch = int(epoch_file.read())
        epoch_file.close()
        accu_file = open(best_path, 'r')
        best_accu = float(accu_file.read())
        accu_file.close()
        improved = 0;
        not_improved = 0;
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess = sess)
        for j in range(1, 1000):
            epoch_file= open(epoch_path, 'w')
            epoch_file.write(str(epoch))
            epoch_file.close()
            for i in range(int(TRAINING_SET_SIZE/BATCH_SIZE)):
                image_out, label_out, label_batch_one_hot_out, filename_out = sess.run([image_batch, label_batch_out, label_batch_one_hot, filename_batch])

                _, infer_out, loss_out, summary, global_step_out = sess.run([train_step, logits_out, loss, merged_summary_op, global_step], feed_dict={image_batch_placeholder: image_out, label_batch_placeholder: label_batch_one_hot_out})


                #print(image_out.shape)
                #print("label_out: ")
                #print(filename_out)
                #print(label_out)
                #print(label_batch_one_hot_out)
                #print("infer_out: ")
                #print(infer_out)
                #print("prediction: ")
                #print(predict_out)
                print("loss: " + str(loss_out))
                print("local step: " + str(i))
                print("global step: " + str(global_step_out - 1))
                print("epoch: " + str(epoch))
                print("improved: " + str(improved))
                print("not improved: " + str(not_improved))
                label_value = label_out
                estimate = infer_out
                err = label_value - estimate
                for k in range (0, 1):
                    print("label value: ", label_value[k], \
                        "estimated value: ", estimate[k])#, \
#                       "err: ", err[i])
                    print("[*]==============================")
                if(i%100 == 0 and i != 0):

                    accuracy_accu = []
                    for p in range(int(v_TRAINING_SET_SIZE/v_BATCH_SIZE)):
                        v_image_out, v_label_out, v_filename_out = sess.run([v_image_batch, v_label_batch, v_filename_batch])
                        v_accuracy_out, v_logits_batch_out= sess.run([accuracy, logits_batch], feed_dict={v_image_batch_placeholder: v_image_out, label_tensor_placeholder: v_label_out})
                        accuracy_accu.append(v_accuracy_out)

                        print(p)
                        print("accuracy: ", v_accuracy_out)
                        print(v_label_out)
                    print("Accuracy: ")
                    print(np.mean(accuracy_accu))
                    print("Best Accuracy: ")
                    print(best_accu)
                    saver.save(sess, chk_path)
                    if((np.mean(accuracy_accu)) > best_accu):
                        print("improved")
                        saver.save(sess, best_chk_path)
                        print("saved")
                        best_accu = np.mean(accuracy_accu)
                        accu_file = open(best_path, 'w')
                        accu_file.write(str(best_accu))
                        accu_file.close()
                        print("New best accuracy!")
                        improved += 1
                    else:
                        print("not improved")
                        not_improved += 1
                if(i%10 == 0):
                    summary_writer.add_summary(summary, global_step_out)                
            epoch += 1
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
        sess.close()

train()
```

Any tips to point me in the right direction would be great. I'll attach a tensorboard image of the logs from the training of this to show you what I mean about the different calls to network()

variable summaries of the different calls to network()

[image]

loss function, in this picture is using the 3rd call to the network that seems to be making guessues

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I keep asking stupid questions, but here was the answer for anyone who has this problem in the future.

I found that since I was going from so many output classes, to just one, it really sped up the convergence speed of the network. The pictures actually just indicate a network that converged to all the same answer in just a few training steps. To fix this, you can set the learning rate to 1/10000th (or something similar)of what it was and get a trainable net. In my case the structure for the classifier was learning well at a.001 rate, but when given just one output neuron I needed a .00000001 learning rate to converge to a more acceptable soltuion. Good luck!